# Calculating and aligning the angles needed to create different corner connectors to join / create various polyhedrons using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, mathematics

Calculating and aligning the angles needed to create different corner connectors to join / create various polyhedrons using geometry nodes.

I'm trying to **create / 3D print** different corner connectors so I can join different polyhedrons together.

Example of polyhedron **angles** I'm trying to get:
[image: img1]

The original file can be located at.
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3472869

I thought I would start with the tetrahedron.  Here are some of the connectors I'm trying out.

[image: img2]
[image: img3]

As you can see **the angles and connectors aren't really aligned correctly**.  **Is there anyway to do this without me manually moving each connector into place (which wouldn't be accurate or correct)**

See attached Blender file.

[image]

PS: I'm using geometry nodes since I thought it would be easier to try / swap out different connectors and adjust their angles for 3D printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is node setup that instead of calculating angles from each edge it will instance each connector on the edge and align it using edge normal and tangent

[image: Dodecahedron ecample]

Then align connectors groups on the ground using singe edge normal of the group

[image]

You can chose just a single group of connector that will be correctly aligned.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great!! and exactly what I was looking for. But I notice that some of the connectors sometimes overlap where they will be connected (at the indented divot ) how can I move the individual connectors out a little bit along the edges?

Comment: @RickT just move connector object in 3d viewport, or use Transform Geometry node after Object Info and translate it in direction you want